# Is there a way to insert a single character string into selected string items in a list?

Tags: python, string, list, append

for example:

```
list = ['a','b','c','d']
```

i want to insert the letter 'j' in front of the first two strings

which will make the list like this

```
list = ['ja','jb','c','d']
```

I know how to append strings into the list but not strings into the items in a list.

Answer (score 3):

You can use list comprehension on a slice and get it done.

```
list1[0:1] = ['j'+x for x in list1[0:2]]
```

The output of this will be:

```
['ja', 'jb', 'c', 'd']
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it is precisely the first two items in the list, why not simply

```
for i in range(2):
    myList[i] = 'j' + myList[i]
```

Also, try not to use the special function `list` as a variable name, hence I changed it to `myList`.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something like this:

```
def appendString(string, array):
    result = []
    for i in array:
        result.append(string + i)

    return result
list = ['a','b','c','d']
list = appendString('j', list)
```

What this will do is create a result array and run through all the items in your list. Each time it find an item in your original list, it will add the string that you want to add at the start (ex. 'j') to the front of the item by performing (ex. 'j' + item) and will add the new string to the result array.